# Perform action in series

Tags: jquery, html

i am trying to perform action in series but here in my code alert message is printed firat though i have written it after some action.

This is Fiddle i have Tried . http://jsfiddle.net/wggua/635/

```
   $(document).ready(function() { 
    var a=1;
    setTimeout(function() { 
        $('#dvData').fadeOut(); 
 }, 2000); 

    if(a==1)
    {
        alert("value i s 1");
    }
    else
    {
         alert("value is 0");   
    }
});
```

Please help,

Answer (score 1):

Your code says:

"Run this fade out function in two seconds. Now alert something."

If you want the alert to appear after the fade out function runs, then you need to put that code inside the function that runs in two seconds too.

Answer (score 1):

The `setTimeout` and `fadeOut` calls are both [asynchronous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchrony) so your alerts fire before either of these have completed. You can pass a callback function to the fadeOut method which will execute when the animation is complete (see [docs](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)). Something like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
    var a=1;
    setTimeout(function() { 
        $('#dvData').fadeOut('slow', function() {
            // This function will execute when the fade out animation is complete
            if(a==1)
            {
                alert("value i s 1");
            }
            else
            {
                 alert("value is 0");   
            }
        }); 
 }, 2000); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want the alerts to appear with the timeout?  If so, your code needs to look like this:-

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
    var a=1;
    setTimeout(function() { 
        $('#dvData').fadeOut(); 
    if(a==1)
    {
        alert("value i s 1");
    }
    else
    {
         alert("value is 0");   
    }

    }, 2000); 


});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wggua/637/

The if statements in your example will run as soon as the document is ready as there is nothing stopping them.  Program execution runs from the top to the bottom in order.

Alternatively, you could run the following code if you wish the alert to show *after* the fadeOut has completed:-

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var a=1;
    setTimeout(function() { 
        $('#dvData').fadeOut(400,function() {
            if(a==1)
            {
                alert("value i s 1");
            }
            else
            {
                 alert("value is 0");   
            }

        }); 

 }, 2000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wggua/638/

Answer (score 0):

You're using `setTimeout`. At time you set it, you have calling a little interval (2 seconds) before the jQuery apply the effect on element. The detail if the `setTimeout` is a function asynchronous. And because this the alert is called before the `jQuery.fadeOut` call.

If you really want the interval, just set a callback with use of the argument `complete` in the `.fadeOut` method, as described here: http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

Here is some example of working code:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
   var a=1;
   function callback(){
       if(a==1)
       {
           alert("value i s 1");
       }
       else
       {
           alert("value is 0");   
       }
   }
   setTimeout(function() { 
      $('#dvData').fadeOut(400, callback); 
   }, 2000); 
});
```

PS: Named function as callbacks is your friend to readability. And the 400 is relative to 400 miliseconds, default to the `jQuery.fadeOut` method.

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fjorgemota/QMVG2/

Good luck.